# ImportError: No module named 'oscar'

Tags: python, django, django-oscar

1.first:
    Install Oscar and its dependencies within a virtualenv:

```
git clone https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar.git
 cd django-oscar
 ll
 virtualenv oscar
 . ./oscar/bin/activate
 sandbox/manage.py runserver
  python -m pip install django
 pip install --upgrade pip
 python -m pip install django
 sandbox/manage.py runserver
  pip install -r requirements.txt
  sandbox/manage.py runserver
```

2.this is my version:

```
(oscar)[root@node02 django-oscar]# python --version
Python 3.5.1
(oscar)[root@node02 django-oscar]# django-admin --version
1.11.1
(oscar)[root@node02 django-oscar]#
```

3.this is error:

```
CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core)

(oscar)[root@node02 django-oscar]# sandbox/manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sandbox/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/root/django-oscar/oscar/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/root/django-oscar/oscar/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 307, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/root/django-oscar/oscar/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/root/django-oscar/oscar/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/root/django-oscar/oscar/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 110, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/root/django-oscar/oscar/lib64/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 662, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/root/django-oscar/sandbox/settings.py", line 3, in <module>  oscar?
    import oscar
ImportError: No module named 'oscar'
```

thank you

Comment: how about trying to install it after activating your virtualenv with pip install django-oscar

Answer (score 3):

For anyone having this problem - 
Please make sure you have done the following:

1. python3 -m venv MY_ENV
2. source MY_ENV/bin/activate
3. pip3 install django-oscar

Note: pip3/python3 can be replaced with pip/python - depending on version